# TypeGraphQL Field Resolver with mongoose relationship

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, graphql, typegraphql

I have trouble dealing with populating the field using TypeGraphQL.

Situation summary with an example:

#### TypeGraphQL

**TypeDef**

```
@ObjectType()
class User {
  ...
}

@ObjectType()
class Post {
  ...

  @Field()
  user: User
}
```

**Resolver**

```
import { Post, User } from '@/models' // mongoose schema 

@Resolver(() => Post)
class PostResolver {
  @Query(() =>. Post)
  async getPost(id: string) {
    return await Post.findById(id);
  }

  ...
  
  @FieldReoslver(() => User) 
  async user(@Root() post: Post) {
    return await User.findById(post.user) // Error Occurs here.
  }
}
```

#### Mongoose

**PostSchema**

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  ...

  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }
})
```

I want to populate `user` field when the data `Post` is requested, with the field  `User` type.
So, I used `@FieldResolver`like above, but I encountered the Type Error because `post.user` is a type of `User`, not `ObjectId` of mongoose.

The `user` field is a type of `ObjectId` first when the `getPost` resolver was executed, but I want to populate this field to `User` when the client gets the response.

How can I get through this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, so maybe you have an answer already. Or maybe this could help someone else.

In your TypeGraphQL typeDef,   `user` would need to be of type `string`.  It could not be of type "User".

Also the name of your FieldResolver would need be different than `user`. However, that would not be follow normal patterns.

So Perhaps in  your typeDef change the `post.user` to `post.userId` instead.    Then the FieldResolver would return a type of "User" for `post.user` allowing you to use readable GraphQL queries.

post.user._id   should then work.